# Equivalent of PreApplicationStartMethod that runs when web.config is available

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have code which relies on configuration information from web.config.  I want it to run when my app starts.  Exactly when is not important as long as it runs.

I know about the `PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute`, but that runs before `web.config` is available.  I also know about the `App_Start` event in `Global.asax`, but I would like to use an attribute if possible.

The app is ASP.NET Web API running on OWIN w/ katana.

Comment: In what sense is web.config "not available" when running within a `PreApplicationStartMethod` method?

Comment: I was getting an error along the lines of "cannot use this in pre app init" when I ran `ConfigurationManager.GetSection` in a `PreApplicationStartMethod `.  I just tried again to post the exact error message and I can no longer repro the issue!  I don't know what changed in between.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was based on an error that is not reproducible.